# Seamless Continues Deployment of Maven project

Tags: tomcat, maven, deployment

Is anybody familiar with step by step instructions to deploy tomcat server(s) that will allow a seamless continues deployment, without cutting off users’ session on every project deployment?
I have a Maven Spring project that I need to launch, knowing that I will have to upgrade continuously.
Any thoughts would be highly appreciated!
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

What you can try to look at is the [maven-cargo-plugin](http://cargo.codehaus.org/Maven2+plugin) which gives you the opportunity to deploy to Tomcat etc. Furthermore there is the [tomcat-maven-plugin](http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2/) which can be used to do deployment on Tomcat. You should take a deep look which fits best for your needs.

Comment: Thank you, I use tomcat-maven-plugin so I'll have to read more to understand how it works with clusters. I found this article: http://www.mulesoft.com/tomcat-clustering which can be helpful